# How to differentiate incoming call for audio or video in SINCH IOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sinch

My app has both sinch audio calling and video calling option, but how should i differentiate the incoming call to whether its audio or video to present respective segues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can look at the details of the incoming call and see if video was offered

https://download.sinch.com/docs/iOS/latest/reference/html/Protocols/SINCallDetails.html

Comment: Thank you, i have used it like if([call.details isVideoOffered]) { }

Comment: Hey, even if i initiate a audio call , the video screen is shown in recipient app.

Comment: try to show and hide UI based on type of audio or video call